# UIView change frame when drag UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, rotation, frame

I have  problem. I have `UIImageView` with `UIButton`.

[image]

When I move `UIButton` as indicated by arrows, I need to change frame `UIImageView` of the button. And I need rotate `UIImageView` when I drag `UIButton` to top.

I think I need add Gesture in the UIButton. But How I can calculate new frame for the `UIImageView`, when I drag `UIButton`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@synthesize resizableImageView;
@synthesize resizeButton;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [resizeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(startDraggableCorner) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [resizeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(stopDraggableCorner) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
-(void)startDraggableCorner
{
    gestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}
-(void)wasDragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    CGRect imageFrame = [resizableImageView frame];
    imageFrame.size.height = [[gesture valueForKey:@"_lastScreenLocation"] CGPointValue].y - imageFrame.origin.y;
    imageFrame.size.width = [[gesture valueForKey:@"_lastScreenLocation"] CGPointValue].x - imageFrame.origin.x;
    [resizableImageView setFrame: imageFrame];
    CGRect buttonFrame = [resizeButton frame];
    buttonFrame.origin.x = [[gesture valueForKey:@"_lastScreenLocation"] CGPointValue].x;
    buttonFrame.origin.y = [[gesture valueForKey:@"_lastScreenLocation"] CGPointValue].y;
    [resizeButton setFrame:buttonFrame];

}
-(void)stopDraggableCorner
{
    [[self view] removeGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}
```

This (almost) succeeds in your resizable behaviour.  Rotating the image, perhaps you can check if `[[gesture valueForKey:@"_lastScreenLocation"] CGPointValue].y` is below a certain amount and then call a method to rotate the image